# McNaughton-Yamada Algotihm (1960) Regular Expression to DFA without passing through NFA

Tags: algorithms, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I have a homework problem here. It asks me to use the McNaughton-Yamada algorithm to first convert a regular expression to a DFA, and then minimize this using a partition argument. I can do the latter. My problem is that I cannot access any actual reference on the algorithm. Their original paper is behind a paywall at IEEE that my university does not have access to.

The algorithm went something like this:
1. For each symbol in the expression, given them a subscript from left to right increasing by one for each instance of that symbol. For example, the expression, aa* would receive a_1 a_2^*.

2. We proceed to construct a diagram based on the possible lengths of words.

If done appropriately, this produces a DFA. I think the labeling in (1) is to help label the states.

Feel free to come up with your own example if you decide to give an answer. I won't provide any problem here because there is no guarantee that it isn't actually my homework exercise.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10493335/940550) and [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82527579.pdf),  the McNaughton–Yamada algorithm produces an NFA rather than a DFA. If you want a DFA, you can determinize your NFA.

Comment: In addition, if course materials aren't enough to do the homework, then (unless it's an advanced class) there is something profoundly wrong going on.

Comment: See this (French but detailed) [Wikipedia entry](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithme_de_McNaughton_et_Yamada).